# Text Histogram, tokens stored in map

Tags: c++, string, text, dictionary

I am reading from a file and take the words as tokens with strtok. I am trying to store the words in a map structure. I don't really know how to insert the tokens in the map.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//std::map <string, int> grade_list;

int main()
{   
    std::map <string, int> grade_list;

    char text[100];
    int nr=0, i=1;
    char *ptr;

    ifstream myfile("ana.txt");

    if(!myfile.is_open())
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
    else
    {
        myfile.get(text, 100);

        ptr = strtok(text, " ,.-?!");

        while(ptr != NULL)
        {
            nr++;

            cout << ptr << endl;
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " ,.-?!");

            grade_list.insert(ptr);

            i++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nAveti " << nr << " cuvinte." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can insert using the insert command . Have a look at examples here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` is an associative container, provides `Key -> Value` relationship. In your case it is `std::string -> int`. So, you should specify `Value` while inserting too:

```
grade_list[ptr] = nr;
```

Also, instead of `char` array and using `strtok` I suggest use `std::string` and [`boost::algorithm::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.split_hpp), or [`boost::tokenizer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm).

---

> I want to see for each word in the file how manny times it appears in the text.

So, you have to change `Value` type in `map` to `std::size_t`(since you din't need to negative values):

```
std::map <string, std::size_t> grade_list;
```

And just write:

```
++grade_list[ptr];
```

Comment: I want to see for each word in the file how manny times it appears in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at the [`std::map::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) definition, the `value_type` parameter is a `std::pair< std::string, int >` so you should probably write the insert statement as:

```
grade_list.insert(std::pair< std::string, int >(std::string(ptr), 1));
```

This will add an entry into the map with the key "token" and the value 1.

What you probably want is more like add an entry if it does not exist or increment the value :

this can be achieved by writing something like

```
if (grade_list.find(ptr) == grade_list.end())
{
    // insert new entry
    grade_list.insert(std::pair< std::string, int >(std::string(ptr), 1)); // can be written as grade_list[ptr] = 1;
}
else
{
    // increment token
    grade_list[ptr] += 1; // can be written as grade_list[ptr]++;
}
```

Comment: Using `insert` is useless here. `operator[]` inserts a new element to the container using key as the key and a default constructed mapped value and returns a reference to the newly constructed mapped value. So, since built-in types default initialized with `0`, there is no need to write `grade_list[ptr] = 1;` even - we just could use `++grade_list[ptr];` in both cases.